# Get Font Awesome container to get bigger on hover (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I've got these FA icons for a bunch of buttons. I would like them to get bigger one at a time when hovering them. The others would consequently move to the sides a bit. I thought about javascript to do that and tried this but it didn't work :

```js
function hoverIcons(classnm) {
  document.getElementById(classnm).css({height: '+=10%', width: '+=10%'});
}

function nothoverIcons(classnm) {
  document.getElementById(classnm).css({height: '+=10%', width: '+=10%'});
}
```

```css
#mainicons{
position:fixed;
bottom:20px;
right:193px;
text-align:center;  
}
 
#mainicons i{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:0;
margin-left:-3px;
height:30px;
width:50px;
padding:10px;
color:{color:Main icon};
background:{color:Main icon background};
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:15px;
line-height:30px;
-webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
-moz-transition: all .7s  ease;
-o-transition: all .7s  ease;
transition: all .7s  ease;
}  
 
#mainicons i:hover{
color:{color:Hover};
background:{color:Main icon};
-webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
-moz-transition: all .7s  ease;
-o-transition: all .7s  ease;
transition: all .7s  ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainicons" onmouseover="hoverIcons('mainicons')" onmouseout="nothoverIcons('mainicons')">
<a href="/" title="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
<a href="/ask" title="Ask"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
<a href="/submit" title="Request"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i></a>
<a href="/archive" title="Archive"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a>
</div>
```

Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try transform for the height and width:

```
#mainicons i:hover {
  color:{color:Hover};
  background:{color:Main icon};
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Hey just a quick question, this did work but the icon is going over the other ones on the sides.. I did this with javascript on another thing (next and back buttons) so the elements moved by themselves when one got bigger.. I don't know if this makes sense this is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWPXVB) of the javascript effect